# Como apagar dados de uma tabela com dependências em outras tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server, dependências

Preciso excluir dados de uma tabela que tem dependências em outras tabelas.
Por exemplo pra que eu possa excluir um dado da tabela pessoa primeiro eu tenho que excluir uma dependência que existe na tabela credencial que por sua vez tem dependência em outra tabela e assim se repete com outras 3 tabelas . O problema é: Não tenho só um dado pra excluir, se não me engano vai de 1000 a 1500. Acho que já tinha ouvido falar em uma forma de excluir dados com dependências com um só script. Só que a agora não encontro já pesquisei em vários lugares mas não encontro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desabilitando e Habilitando as constraints de chave estrangeira. Os comandos são os seguintes:

## Para SQL Server:

```
-- Desabilita todas as constraints de uma tabela

ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

-- Habilita todas as constraints de uma tabela

ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

-- Desabilita uma constraint

ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela NOCHECK CONSTRAINT MinhaConstraintDeFk

-- Habilita uma constraint

ALTER TABLE MinhaTabela CHECK CONSTRAINT MinhaConstraintDeFk
```

---

## Para MySQL:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
// Delete o que tiver que deletar

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;  
// Ative a checagem novamente

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;  
// Delete o que tiver que deletar

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;  
// Ative a checagem novamente
```

---

citações:

1. [Resposta do Stack Overflow (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737115/turn-off-constraints-temporarily-ms-sql)
2. [Foreign Key Checks (referência do MySQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)

Comment: mas tenho que fazer isso pra todas as tabelas?

Comment: @PatiiHenrii Você quer o comando pra todas as tabelas também? Não recomendo. O ideal é usar somente para as tabelas envolvidas com a sua alteração.

Comment: entendi, vou testar aqui, no banco de teste que tenho! obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;  
// Delete o que tiver que deletar

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;  
// Ative a checagem novamente
```

Comment: Se este comando existisse seria uma boa. Onde você viu isso? Pode incluir um link para a documentação do comando? Na verdade até a sintaxe do uso do SET está errada. Me parece que você não observou que o banco é MS SQL Server (este comando aí é do MySql).

Answer (score 4):

Quando for criar um relacionamento entre as tabelas coloque o `on delete` e `delete update` em `cascade`.

Exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE `tab_audiencia` ADD CONSTRAINT `tab_audiencia_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `escala`.`usuarios`(`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Assim quando for apagado o registro da tabela "usuario" os demais relacionamentos serão apagados automaticamente

Answer (score 3):

Sei que o post já tem 1 ano, mas como sempre os usamos como referência, gostaria de fazer um alerta.

A ideia do Cigano é bem pontual e deve ser usada com extremo cuidado. Desligar constraints não é uma boa prática, principalmente usando usando o complemento `ALL`. Você fica sem saber quais constraints foram desligadas e por consequência não fica sabendo quais são as tabelas envolvidas.

Se deixar uma tabela "filha" sem ser limpa ela ficará com "lixo" e pra ajudar, todas as vezes que limpamos uma tabela é normal dar um `reset` nas sequences. Ai já viu. Vai chegar um momento em que nossa sequência alcançará registros antigos e se misturá às informações novas. Já da para saber onde isso vai dar.

Esse post não é uma critica ao seu autor, é apenas uma recomendação de cuidado ao seu uso.

Comment: Faltou dizer qual opção é melhor do que aquela.

Comment: Concordo com @Caffé. Sinta-se à vontade para elaborar um pouco mais a sua resposta com uma implementação do que você considera a abordagem correta, Sérgio - no momento é mais um comentário do que uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você manipula dados de um banco de dados, presume-se que você conhece o banco, ou você não saberia o que está fazendo.

Desativar as constraints temporariamente resolve? Não creio pois depois você terá que ligar de volta então de qualquer modo não poderá ter corrompido o relacionamento dos registros.

> Ou seja: você não escapa de saber o que está fazendo, precisa conhecer previamente os relacionamentos e precisa saber das implicações de se excluir um registro com dependências.

A opção que mais faz sentido para mim é **excluir os registros na ordem das suas dependências, primeiro os filhos e depois os pais**, em vez de fingir ignorar estas dependências.

Você ainda poderá fazer a exclusão em massa: exclua os 1500 registros filhos, depois os 1500 registros pai e depois os pais destes e assim por diante.

Se a exclusão das dependências ao deletar um pai for um procedimento padrão para estas tabelas, então eu fico com a opção do Math: alterar a tabela de modo a tornar automática e definitiva a exclusão de dependências.

## Agora, se você realmente não liga para os dados

Se você estiver por exemplo usando uma base de testes pode ser aplicável de vez em quando sair excluindo registros e destruindo dependências como se não houvesse amanhã.

Neste caso uma opção é um script que recupere os metadados da tabela e percorra as dependências fazendo a exclusão na ordem correta.

Este script pode ser um código quebra-galho no lado do cliente na linguagem da sua preferência, ou uma stored procedure.